# how to use knitr::spin to convert R script to html file with interactive plots

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown, plotly

I want to generate some Rmarkdown file from r script using `knitr::spin`  with interactive plots. but the plots it generates are static and located in the figure subfolder. How could I generate keep the interactive plots?

here is an example:

```
#' ---
#' title: "test me"
#' output:
#'   html_notebook:
#'     code_folding: hide
#'     toc: true
#'     toc_float: true
#'     collapsed: false
#' ---
#+ warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

#' ## interactive cars
data(cars)
ggplotly(ggplot(data=cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))+geom_point())

#' ## interactive table
datatable(cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because you're making two calls for a widget in the same chunk. When I run your code on RStudio as an Rmd file, the RNotebook file seems to stack the plots (which may be what you mean).

When I separate the function calls between two chunks, though, all appears fine. I generate the following output (which you can see here on RPubs): http://rpubs.com/p0bs/285465. (In order to get the code, just click the dropdown in the RPubs document and click *SAVE RMD*.)

I hope this helps you.